# PIL: module object has no attribute 'resize'

Tags: image, python-2.7, powershell, python-imaging-library

I'm trying PIL and it is throwing an error which I find strange.

this is all the code I have:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageOps

im = ("lenna.png")
imResize = Image.resize((200,200), Image.ANTIALIAS)
```

I'm doing this on command line via Windows Powershell and the first two statements gave
me no problem. Indeed I even tried `im.show()` and the image opened but when I tried the `imResize`, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'resize'
```

Yet when I go through `help(Image)` I can see the `resize` method there and I seem to be doing everything alright.

Please is there anything I'm missing?
Thanks

Comment: Sorry,I should have called the `resize` method on the variable instead. So `im.resize()` gets the job done instead of `Image.resize()`
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

[Putting the answer as an answer :)]

Call the resize method on the variable instead. So `im.resize()` gets the job done instead of `Image.resize()`.